# Laravel view, sort based on two criteria

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to order the out but based on two criteria's, the dawn one should come at the top and then the up and last the no active once. I am trying to do it in the view in laravel. this is my code. it is able to sort them based on up or dawn but not on active.

```
@foreach($notes->sortBy('values') as $notification)       

    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td> {{ $notification->website_url }} </td>
            @if($notification->status('health') == 'up')
            <td> {{ $notification->status('health') }} <span class="up"></span></td>
            @else
            <td> {{ $notification->status('health') }}  <span class="down"></span></td>
            @endif 
            <td>  </td>
            <td class="<?php echo $notification->active == 1 ? 'active' : '' ?>">                         
                {{ $notification->active == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('notifications.edit', [$notification->id]) }}">
                    <input type="submit" name="showmore" value="show more"/>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument of `sortBy()` method can be actually a function, so you can use custom value as a sort criteria. Preferably in the Controller.

```
$notes = $notes->sortBy(function ($note) {
    return ($note->active ? '0' : '1') . ($note->status('health') == 'down' ? '0' : '1');
});
```

And `$notes` will be sorted by this value in the following order:

1. `00` for down active
2. `01` for up active
3. `10` for down not active
4. `11` for up not active

To be sincere though I'm not really sure if I understand what order you want to achieve. If that is the case just adjust the return value of sorting function.

Comment: u alright get my point right. I used your code to try it. it looks to work but. the result is a bit strange thought. the order i get is

Comment: Did you delete `$notes->sortBy('values')` from your loop? It should be just `$notes`.

Comment: Yes I deleted it and I replaced it with the new code you wrote. This is my newforeach loop

Comment: @foreach($notes = $notes->sortBy(function ($note) {
                 return ($note->active ? '0' : '1') . ($note->health == 'down' ? '0' : '1');
                 }); as $notification)

Comment: tnx i figured out though. i have a function in the model colled status.  
@foreach($notes = $notes->sortBy(function ($note) { return ($note->active ? '0' : '1') . ($note->status('health') == 'down' ? '0' : '1'); }); as $notification)

Comment: My bad, updated the solution. Glad it works now, please accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: i hope i have accepted it... but if iam not doing what u wanted me to do. inform me more. iam very new to programming and stack overflow. tnx